# Bittrex API returns APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED in Postman

Tags: rest, api, postman

I'm trying to use Bittrex API in Postman, but all API calls return "APIKEY_NOT_PROVIDED". I am pretty sure this is because Bittrex requires SHA512 HMAC authentication, so does anyone know how to overcome this? Any pre-request script that can be used or even a Postman environment that can be imported?

Binance has a Postman environment for SHA256 HMAC authentication (https://github.com/binance-exchange/binance-api-postman) that makes this super easy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is some Pre-request Script which I used some time ago in Postman to create HMAC-SHA256 signature, it should give you the idea how to modify it specifically for Binance request.

```
var ts = Math.round((new Date().getTime()/1000));
var key = 'YOUR_API_KEY';
var secret = 'YOUR_API_SECRET';

var createSig = function() {
    var hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, secret);
    hmac.update(ts.toString());
    hmac.update(request.method.toUpperCase());
    hmac.update(request.url);
    hmac.update(request.method === 'GET' ? '' : request.data);
    return hmac.finalize();
};

postman.setGlobalVariable('ts', ts);
postman.setGlobalVariable('key', key);
postman.setGlobalVariable('sig', createSig());
```

The script will set 3 variables:

- `ts` - current unix timestamp
- `key` - API key
- `sig` - HMAC calculated signature

Use them in Postman's request headers as shown on screenshot, modified to fit the Binance request:

[image]